# Turning off "Wy-60" in 4GL Informix?

Tags: terminal, informix, telnet, 4gl

We have an Informix 4GL forms interface to our database, accessed using a terminal emulator running in WY-60 or "Wyse-60" terminal emulation mode.

From what I'm reading, where I would previously understood a "terminal" to just be a display of a text stream (e.g. Hyperterm), "WY-60" mode means that the software is emulating a 1980s-era computer, which is performing display operations based on the data sent within the text stream, resulting in a high degree (for the time) of graphical capability with only a very small expenditure of data traffic.

What I'm wondering is, what alternatives do I have to this in 4GL Informix?

The menu-driven interface of the 4GL forms will presumably require something better than a pure text-stream terminal... but how much work would it be to change from our current, proprietary (requiring expensive terminal emulation software) WY-60 type display to something else which could, for instance, work with the free PuTTY terminal software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are all sorts of things to discuss here, but the basic answer is:

- Change the setting of the `TERM` environment variable to a different value from `wy-60`.

What are the issues:

1. You need to know whether you are using `termcap` or `terminfo`.  This is controlled by the `INFORMIXTERM` environment variable, which can be set to `termcap` or `terminfo` or could be unset in which case it defaults to `termcap`.
2. You need to know where your alternative terminal description will come from.

   - If you are using `termcap`, you will need to ensure that the `TERMCAP` variable is set correctly, either to the name of file (default is `/etc/termcap`; Informix provides a file in `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/termcap`) or the text of the entry for the terminal.
   - If you are using `terminfo`, you can specify where the terminal entries are stored in the `TERMINFO` environment variable.  It will be a directory name; under that will be a series of directories each with a single character name (the first character of a terminal name), with the actual terminal descriptions in a file.  Thus, if `TERMINFO=$HOME/terminfo` and `TERM=wy-60`, the `terminfo` code will look for the file `$HOME/terminfo/w/wy-60`.
3. You need to be sure that the relevant description for your new terminal is available.  You can use any terminal type that is described by `termcap` or `terminfo`.  However, Informix does use some extra capabilities (documented in an appendix to the I4GL Reference Manual) under `termcap`.
4. You'll need to check that the I4GL program looks clean on your new terminal type.

You might look at `xterm` or `xterm-color` or `ansi` or `vt100` or any of a large number of other terminal types.  The only reason to stay with Wyse 60 is that it is known to work.

Answer (score 1):

WY-60 (a.k.a. Altos 2 terminal) works the best. You also have the alternative of converting the char-based I4GL forms to GUI-based forms with IBM Informix Genero (I4GL-compatible).. I noticed you withdrew your question about connecting to Informix via Visual Studio.. Did you resolve that?

Comment: The answer that came back to me on the connection question was that we're having some work done on the system by a high-paid consultant and he'll resolve the connection issues, therefore I should move on to other work. Seeing as I won't be involved in that (the servers and the consultant are on another site) and so won't actually know what the answer was to any useful degree, I decided to close the question. If I *do* get an answer back that I understand, I'll bring the question back and answer it as best I can.

Comment: Well, that's one less issue added to your workload. However, if you anticipate that in the future you will be interacting with Informix, I suggest that you familiarize yourself with it, time permitting.